# Accessing and Saving Settings From Combo Box From Different Class

Tags: c#, combobox

I currently have a form class that handles combo boxes called "Settings". In the combo box are a list of seconds to select, ie. 30 Seconds, 60 Seconds. This seems really simple but I can't get my head around it!

I currently have this in the Settings class where the combo boxes are used

```
    private void timeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        timeSelected = this.timeSelect.GetItemText(this.timeSelect.SelectedItem);

        if (timeSelected == "120 Seconds")
            seconds = 120;                   
    }
```

The variable seconds being a public int in that class. In a different class called Time, I want to be able to access this integer so I can set the timer value to whatever has been selected. I tried making a method in Time that takes in the int, called it in the Settings class so it saves the value into a variable in the Time class. Something like this:

In the Time class:

```
public int j;
public void timeChosen(int secondsChosen)
{
     j = secondsChosen;
}
```

and called the method above in the Settings class to pass the value "seconds"

However, this doesn't work and when application starts the value of j as 0. But when it's first called, it does take into account that the value might be 120 but it does not seem to save the value.

Any suggestions?

In Settings class:

```
Time time = new Time();
public int seconds;
public string timeSelected;

private void timeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
           timeSelected = this.timeSelect.GetItemText(this.timeSelect.SelectedItem);

            if (timeSelected == "120 Seconds")
                seconds = 120;                   
        }

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time.timeChosen(seconds);
        this.Hide();
        var nextForm = new NextForm();
        nextForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In Time class:

```
public int j;
    public void timeChosen(int secondsChosen)
    {
         j = secondsChosen;
    }
```

The timer is set up in a different class but that all works fine, it's just a matter of passing and saving the value from the combo box. As in the Time class I can just set it to public int j = 60; and it sees it as 60 seconds and works.

Comment: Can you show how do you initiate  the Time object? do you always create it before you call `timeChosen`?

Comment: @Valentin Sorry, I mistyped. I meant I called the method timeChosen from the Time Class and pass in the seconds variable which is in the Settings class. Stepping through it, it does save the value into j when it's called but the application carries on and once the seconds value is needed, it just gives the value 0 instead. So it never is saved into the variable j in the Time class. I was trying to make it work so in the mean time I just created an instance of the Time class in the Settings class so I can access the method.

Comment: Can you provide more code please. Thanks

Comment: @Valentin I provided a bit more. I call in the timeChosen method when the user clicks next to move onto the next form. As mentioned, it does work and pass in the value when called but it does not seem to save it into the variable that I want in the Time class.

Comment: And you are trying to get `Time.j` in the `nextForm`, aren't you?

Comment: Pretty much in a way. I'm trying to get `Settings.seconds` into `Time.j`. I'm basically storing some values into Time class and in other Forms I access the Time Class. So once the value of `Settings.seconds` is stored into `Time.j`. I can then go into 'nextForm' and access `Time.j`.

Comment: Are you sure, that `seconds` is not 0?

Comment: It's not set to 0 no. When I step through, it calls the method, it goes into the Time class. Sets `Time.j` to 120. Proceeds onto the next couple of forms and when the application is started (when the `Time.j` is actually used) its no longer recognised as 120 but back to 0.

Comment: "when the application is started (when the Time.j is actually used) its no longer recognised as 120 but back to 0" So you want to save settings and then load them when application starts, don't you?

Comment: I see. I actually did not know that it resets back to null. I want to be able to save the value of seconds yes so it can be used when it's needed. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [standard application settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx). 
You need to create a setting file and add a new variable in the settings

1. Right click on a project in the solution explorer
2. Go to Properties -> Settings Tab and create a new setting file
3. Then create a new int variable `Seconds` in the grid view on the
   same page.

So after, you will be able to `get/set` this setting variable using  `Properties.Settings.Default.Seconds`

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Seconds = seconds;
    this.Hide();
    var nextForm = new NextForm();
    nextForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly! Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: @Jed5931 You are welcome. Probably need to update your question, so everyone can understand what's going on. Thanks